# one-sided limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$ where wolfram alpha does not help

Tags: limits

The function $f$ is defined as follows:
$$f(x):=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!} e^{-x}$$

It's easy to see that $f(0)=0$. But I am interested in the value 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x).$$

Even [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%28x-%3E0%29+%28sum_%28i%3D1%29%5Einfinity+x%5Ej%2F%28j%21%29+e%5E%28-x%29%29+) does not help here. I tried to plot this function, but this doesn't work neither. And my calculator doesn't give a solution for concrete values of $x$, so I have no idea how to get on here.

Comment: Do you believe this $f$ is continuous in $x$ at zero?  Why or why not?

Comment: Do you want the sum to be over $j$ rather than $i$?

Comment: Recall the definition of the exponential function: $e^x=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^j}{j!}$.

Comment: Also, you had an error in your entry in Wolfram Alpha: [here is the correct version](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%28x-%3E0%29+%28sum_%28j%3D1%29%5Einfinity+x%5Ej%2F%28j%21%29e%5E%28-x%29%29+)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. 
Thank to my silly mistake in typing i instead of j (in this post, on Wolfram Alpha as well as on my calculator) (without this mistake I wouldn't have posted this question) and your help I now have a derivation of this Limit.

Thank you all very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ f(x) =\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}e^{-x} = e^{-x}\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!} = e^{-x}\cdot (e^x-1) = 1-e^{-x}.$$

Here we have used that 
$$e^x = \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j!} = 1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j!} $$
So that
$$ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j!} = e^x-1.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that $$f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j!}e^{-x} = e^{-x}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j!} = e^{-x}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j!}-1\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha can [do this limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BSum%5Bx%5Ej/j!%20E%5E-x,%20%7Bj,%201,%20%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D,%20x%20-%3E%200,%20Direction%20-%3E%20-1%5D).  "Direction->-1" means to approach the limit from larger values.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $e^x=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\frac{x^j}{j!}$.

So $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!} e^{-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!} e^{-x}-e^{-x}=1-e^{-x}$