# closed-form term for this sum:

Tags: summation, exponentiation, infinity, closed-form, exponential-sum

related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830599/one-sided-limit-lim-x-rightarrow-0-fx-where-wolfram-alpha-does-not-hel):

Is there an easy closed-form term for

$$\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!}e^{-x},$$

thus when the sum starts at a constant $k$ instead of $1$?

EDIT:
Thanks for your help. Is there a Chance to solve this sum-term? Because this is not really what I expect, when I talk about a closed-form term.

A Little bit more of context might help, maybe:

I have $$f(n,p)=\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \frac{(np)^j}{j!} e^{-np}$$ and it is meant that the partial Derivation is $$\frac{\delta f(n,p)}{\delta n}=\frac{p (np)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-np}$$ but I have no idea how to get to this.

Because to me:

$$\frac{\delta f(n,p)}{\delta n}=\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \left( \frac{p (np)^{j-1}}{j!} e^{-np} -\frac{p (np)^j}{j!} e^{-np} \right)$$
but then I am stuck.

Comment: See [CDF of Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Comment: From $\displaystyle{\large\tt M}$: $\displaystyle{\large\frac{\Gamma (k)-\Gamma (k,x)}{\Gamma (k)}}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin
Could you specify what you mean with that? I know about the Gamma and the incomplete Gamma functions, but I can't see how to apply this here.

Comment: I just put your expression in $\tt Mathematica$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just made a mistake when differentiating $$f(x)=\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \frac{(xp)^j}{j!} e^{-xp}.$$
The actual derivative is
$$f'(x)=\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \left( \color{red}{j}\,\frac{p\,(xp)^{j-1}}{j!} e^{-xp} -\frac{p\,(xp)^j}{j!} e^{-xp} \right),$$
that is, provided $k\geqslant1$, using the change of indices $\ell=j-1$ in the first summation,
$$f'(x)=\sum_{\ell=k-1}^{\infty}\frac{p(xp)^{\ell}}{\ell!} e^{-xp} -\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \frac{p (xp)^j}{j!} e^{-xp}=\frac{p(xp)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} e^{-xp}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!}e^{-x}=
\left(\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{x^j}{j!}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{x^j}{j!}\right)e^{-x}\\
=\left(e^x-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{x^j}{j!}\right)e^{-x}=1-e^{-x}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{x^j}{j!}
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. I stated above in the question the whole Problem, pointing out what I could mean with a closed form, because somehow I don't get how they got to this solution.

Comment: @mookid correct but my sum's upper limit is $k-1$, or did I miss something...

Comment: you are right. But I don't know if it is what OP was looking for....

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

$$e^{-x}\sum_{j=k}^\infty \frac 1{j!} x^j =
e^{-x}\left[\exp x - \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac 1{j!} x^j \right]
=e^{-x}\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} e^{t} dt
$$

Comment: $x$ as limit and inside the integral looks a little strange. Are you sure?

Comment: x does not appear as a limit, does it?

Comment: $e^{-x}\int_0^{\color{red}x}$...

Comment: there is no error, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder

Comment: @draks...: it would only seem strange to me if $x$ were the variable of integration, but $t$ is the variable of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete Gamma function and Eq.2 in : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html

[image]